# How to tell which partitions to backup in recovery (TWRP)?

Tags: backup, twrp, partitions

I have TWRP as my recovery on a Galaxy phone. There are so many options to choose which partitions to backup. What do they all do? My goal is to be able to recover from the largest number of disasters. However I think restoring some partitions can lead to a boot loop, because this recently happened to me.

Comment: depending on TWRP fstab you should see only rom related partitions. for full backup compare partition list from terminal *'ls -d $(find /dev/block -name by-name)/\*'* usually all (or most) partitions can be downloaded, no need to backup. for daily use just backup */boot /system /vendor /data /data/media/0* and do not wipe other partitions